# Use datePicker for countdown

Tags: nstimer, uidatepicker, countdowntimer, nstimeinterval

I want to let the user set a countdown with choosing the timeintervall by a datePicker.
I only have the layout, but don't know how to program it as I'm very new to Xcode:
[image]

The time should count down in the label when the button is clicked.
Thanks to everyone in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having sort of the same trouble.  Check out this tutorial.  It's very in-depth and it should be what you need.  :)

http://code-and-coffee.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-make-countdown-app.html